# Removing V channel from HSV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hsv, color-space

I'm trying to eliminate the V channel from an image (HSV).  Am I doing it right?

```
cvtColor( image, image, CV_BGR2HSV );

//Copy only relevant channels into the output image:
// hsv[0] -> channel[0] 
// hsv[1] -> channel[1],
// hsv[2] -> channel[0] 
//Mat dst[]={hsv};

int from_to[] = {0, 0, 1, 1};

mixChannels( &image, 1,&image, 1, from_to, 2 );
```

Comment: Could you better format your code? Like what's the signature of the function and how is it being called

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate"?  The value channel essentially is the intensity of the colour.  By eliminating this channel, all of the pixels would be dark.  Can you elaborate?  If you want to do what your comments say, you need to change `from_to` to this: `int from_to[] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2};`, then do: `mixChannels( &image, 1,&image, 1, from_to, 3);`.

Comment: I was applying LBP to images in gray-scale. LBP is variant to illumination. I was wondering if pre-processing the image by removing the V channel and adjusting the LBP threshold could solve the illumination problem. Will it work ? –

Comment: No, probably not.  The `V` channel in the HSV colour space works in concert with the way we perceive colours, so removing the intensity of the particular colour will not work in the way you want it to.  Also, as far as I know, LBP is defined for grayscale images.  Perhaps you should seek to normalize the images instead of trying to remove the `V` channel.  Try normalizing your images first so that they exhibit zero-mean and unit-variance, then try using LBP on that result.